# How to create custom breakpoints in magento2?

Tags: magento2, theme, custom, less

How can i create custom breakpoint with `min and max` like `@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width: 1023px)  {...}` in my custom theme in magento 2.1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom variable in your `custom_theme/web/css/source/_variable.less` e.g

```
@custom__breakpoint: 1200px;
```

Copy **_responsive.less** file from **lib/web/css/source/lib/_responsive.less** to **custom_theme//web/css/source/lib/** use `.media-width()` mixin to add the new breakpoint e.g.

```
& when (@media-target = 'desktop'), (@media-target = 'all') {
@media all and (min-width: @custom__breakpoint) {
    .media-width('min', @custom__breakpoint);
}
```

You can now call `.media-width()` mixin in your less file e.g.

```
@media screen and(min-width: @custom__breakpoint) {
...
}
```

Further read https://goo.gl/FS2271

`.media-width()` doesn't let you add both min and max widths, to achieve that you either have to write a new mixin or alternatively (which makes more sense) create two breakpoints (min and max as per your required values) and use them in the call e.g.

`@media all and (max-width: @custom__max-width) and (min-width: @custom__min-width) { 
...
 }`

Comment: Thanks for answer @Devtype, But i want to use `min and max` width together which i mentioned.